# Actions on GoogleでFirebaseトークンを取得したい

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud

Actions on GoogleでFirebaseトークンを取得したい

Google Cloud Platform(GCP)上のGoogle App Engine(GAE)でアプリを作成しました。
認証には、Firebase Authenticationを使用しています。

GCP上に上記GAEのアプリとは、別のプロジェクトでActions on GoogleでVUIアプリを作成しようとしています。
GAEアプリでCloud Datastoreに保存しているデータをActions on GoogleのアプリからRESET APIを使用して取得したいと思っています。

RESET APIを使用するには、GAEアプリの認証用のFirebaseトークンが必要となっています。
Actions on Googleアプリからは、Googleアカウント(xxx@gmail.com)は取得でき、Googleアカウントのアクセストークンは取得できています。

Actions on GoogleのAccountLinking機能等を使って、GAEアプリのFirebaseトークンを取得することは可能なのでしょうか？
可能であるなら、Firebaseトークンの取得方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: 以前に同じような質問に回答( https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43560 )したことがあるのですが、この回答で問題あるでしょうか。今回は別プロジェクトですが、WebhookでGAEのアプリと同じプロジェクトで作った Cloud Functions for Firebase に飛ばせばいいと思うのですが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43560とは、違った話となっており、別プロジェクトになっておりまして、GAEで作ったアプリの方のデータストアには直接アクセスできないようになっております。

データを取得するには、GAEアプリのRESET APIを使用する必要がありまして、その為には、Firebaseトークンが必要となっています。

Actions on GoogleのAccountLinkingで、GAEアプリの方の認証用のFirebaseに飛ばして、Firebase Authenticationでアクセストークンを取得できないかなと思っておりまして、
その方法が現状、分かってない状況となっております。

Comment: Dialogflow の FulfillmentにFirebaseトークンを取得するルーチンを書いたらどうでしょうか。マニュアルは https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?hl=ja

Answer (score 0):

Actions on GoogleのAccountLinking 機能を使って、取得できるのはGoogleアカウントとそれのアクセストークンです。それを使って Firebaseで認証することが可能です。

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?hl=ja

今回のケースであれば、アプリが動作しているGAEに、Googleアカウントとそれのアクセストークンを渡せばFirebaseトークンがなくても、Firebaseでの認証が可能です。

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?hl=ja
こちらで参考にするのは、
「高度: Node.js 内で Firebase で認証する」で宜しいでしょうか？

試しに、サンプルコードをindex.jsに記載してみましたが、
var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
のところで、以下のエラーとなってしまいました。
「TypeError: Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined at exports.testMethod」

何か原因等分かりますでしょうか？

Comment: 「高度: Node.js 内で Firebase で認証する」は難しいので使ったことがありません。Firebaseトークンを渡すというのは結構ややこしい話なので、自分がプログラムするのであれば、回答のようにGAEの方でFirebase認証のプログラムを書くか、GAEのプログラムをコピーしてFulfillmentの方で動かします。

Comment: この質問をみてずっと疑問なのが、GAEの方に Actions on Google からのアクセス専用のAPIをなぜ作らないのかということです。専用のAPIを作れば、Googleアカウントは認証の方はActions on Googleの方で対応してくれるので、こちら側で意識をする必要はないと思うのです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
「GAEの方に Actions on Google からのアクセス専用のAPIを作成」につきましては、最後の手段として考えておりました。
可能であるなら、APIを作成しない方向で、実現したいと思っております。
現状は「Dialogflow の FulfillmentにFirebaseトークンを取得するルーチンを書いたらどうでしょうか。マニュアルは firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?hl=ja」
のアドバイスを参考にFirebaseトークンを取得を試行しています。
できないようでしたら、API作成にしたいと思います。